# Tasks fail without emitting logs in Airflow

Tags: airflow, airflow-celery, airflow-k8s

dags fail while no logs are displayed, but at the same time you can still start them from 3-4 attempts.
We use pdiOperator(pentaho data integration), that is, for each dag, a separate pod is formed in the Kubernetes, in which it is executed. That is, in fact, the logs are not displayed, because it does not reach the moment of generating pdi for the dag, but I don’t understand why.
Most importantly, in the logs on the scheduler and worker, nothing is displayed marked error.
We are using:

- airflow v 2.3.1 in Kuber (2 webs, 2 workers, 2 schedulers)
- celery executor (concurrency 9, i.e. only 18, because there are two workers)
- pentaho data integration (pdiOperator)
- rabbitmq 3.8.19 also in Kubernetes
- postgresql 13 for meta already on a separate local machine
- also in each pod there is a git-sync container to synchronize the dags code

What have we tried:

- increased the value of the dagbag_import_timeout variables to 300 and dag_file_processor_timeout to 350 and after about a month everything worked like clockwork, but then it appeared again
- again increased to 600 and 650 respectively, worked for a week and started again
- after that, set sleep 60 (called initialstartupdelay in helmchart's values) before loading the pod on the pod scheduler, worker and web, because they suspected that they did not have time to load the dag code that was copied using git-sync pods, but this did not help either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably caused by [tasks becoming zombies](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/core-concepts/tasks.html#zombie-undead-tasks). A zombie task is one that the Airflow database thinks is running but hasn't emitted a heartbeat for a certain amount of time. There are a lot of things that can cause zombies. Some examples include:

- The worker runs out of memory.
- The network connection between the worker and airflow database is severed.
- [Bugs that are fixed in newer versions of Airflow](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/24906)

I recommend checking to see if the worker ran out of memory. If it didn't, I'd probably recommend upgrading to a newer version of Airflow or deep-diving the scheduler logs to see why the task became a zombie.